# Executing NodeJS script From PHP (Laravel), not finding Node Modules in production

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, node-modules

I have this function in my API Controller that executes a node file and it works normally on localhost, here is the script.

**GifApiController.php**

```
public function saveAndDissectGif(Request $request) {
        $gif = $request->file;
        //save the file temporarily in the asset-uploader directory
        Storage::disk('roblogif')->put('/',$gif);
        //dissect the gif into frames and get the frame count
        $output = $this->executeNodeFile('dissectGif.js');

        $frame_count = $output[0];

        //there's a 6.5 second delay between each frame, divide by 60 to get it in minutes
        //assume that 20 percent of the frames will fail, which means 20 percent will have a 1 minute delay
        $time_in_minutes = $frame_count * ( 6.5 / 60 ) + ( ( $frame_count * 0.2 ) );
        return ceil($time_in_minutes);
    }

private function executeNodeFile($javascript_file_name) {
        exec("cd ".__DIR__."; cd ../../asset-uploader; node ".$javascript_file_name, $output, $err);
        if($err)
            return $err;
        return $output;
    }
```

dissectGif.js gets all the frames from a gif and saves them in a folder (using the gif-frames library). To get the output from the file, I am console logging it.

**dissectGif.js**

```
const fs = require("fs")
const gifFrames = require('gif-frames');

async function startApp() {

    // get the gif
    let gif = fs.readdirSync("./gif");
    gif = gif[Object.keys(gif)[0]];

    // dissect gif into frames
    await gifFrames({ url: './gif/'+gif, frames: 'all', outputType: 'png', cumulative: true }).then(function (frameData) {
        frameData.forEach(async function (frame) {
            await frame.getImage().pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./gif-frames/'+frame.frameIndex+'.png'));
        });
    });
    //get and return the frame count so we can estimate loading time
    return fs.readdir('./gif-frames', (err, files) => { 
        console.log(files.length)
        return files.length
    });
}

startApp()
```

This works great on localhost. $output[0] in GifApiController.php gets the files.length from the dissectGif.js file. But when I host the site, I get an error saying ***Undefined array key 0*** which makes me think that in production mode, it's not finding the fs and the gif-frames libraries.

I tried to put the full directory of the libraries such as:

```
const fs = require("../../node_modules/fs")
```

but that didn't work. I also tried running npm install before executing the script but that didn't work as well.

I thought the issue could be from the gif not getting saved, but i checked and it was.

Does anybody have an idea on how to solve this issue?